# Matching the IP using regular expression

Tags: regex, tcl

```
set ip 10.10.

if {[regexp
{^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.?){4}$} $ip
match]} {   puts $match }
```

the above pattern matching `10.10.` can anyone tell me how this happening

Comment: have a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/gW4fW6/1) regex. It validates IPv4 and IPv6 adresses. This regex is from a validation rule of the [CakePHP](https://github.com/cakephp)-Framework

Comment: Isn't is easier to split the IP into pieces then iteratively check each of them against the range of valid values?

Comment: `1`, `1.1`, `1.1.1` and `1.1.1.1` are all valid IPv4 addresses. IPv6 has even more variations.

Answer (score 4):

First, using a regular expression to check ip addresses is extremely fragile and unnecessarily complex, and you still have to do the heavy lifting yourself. Instead, use the Tcllib_ip package.

```
package require ip
```

If you want to know if a given string is an IPv4 address, just check with

```
::ip::is 4 $str    ;# 1 if valid ipv4, 0 otherwise
```

or

```
::ip::version $str ;# returns 4 or 6 for ipv4 or ipv6, -1 otherwise
```

The commands in the package also handle address strings that aren't dotted decimal.

The package isn't included in all distributions, but can be installed using `teacup install` or by downloading the files and sourcing them into the script.

To answer the question: the original asker has one error and one problem. The error is that the regular expression used to match the ip address also matches strings that aren't ip addresses. This is one of the most common problems when using regular expressions. The reason and the fix is addressed in other answers to the question. To recap: Captain noted that since the original regular expression makes the dot optional, the string `10.10.` can be matched as `1 0. 1 0.`. There are several possible solutions: `{^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.|$)){4}$}` as suggested by the same Captain seems valid but may turn out to have more problems if tested.

The main problem is that a non-trivial regular expression is used to match the address. For all but the most trivial regular expressions, rigorous testing must be performed to ensure that they don't produce false positives. *This testing is usually impractical to make exhaustive*, which means that you can't know for sure if it works until an angry customer tells you it doesn't. When a case of false positive match is found, the solution is either to drop the regular expression and try another method, or alternatively to make the regular expression more complex in order to make the match more strict. At this point, the test suite may also have to grow.

A better way is to step back and look for other solutions. If there is a standard library function for it, that should be used. If we imagine there is none in this case, simply reflecting on the most basic formulation of an ipv4 decimal-dot address ("four groups of integers from 0 to 255, joined by dots") suggests some simple and safe functions:

```
proc isOctet n {
    expr {[string is integer -strict $n] && 0 <= $n && $n <= 255}
}

proc splitIpv4dd1 str {
    split $str .
}

proc splitIpv4dd2 str {
    scan $str %d.%d.%d.%d
}

proc splitIpv4dd3 str {
    lrange [regexp -inline {^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$} $str] 1 end
}

# plug any of the preceding splitIpv4ddN functions into this command
proc putsIpv4dd str {
    set count 0
    foreach n [splitIpv4dd1 $str] {
        if {[isOctet $n]} {
            incr count
        }
    }
    if {$count == 4} {puts $str}
}
```

It is much easier to verify that each of these functions does its job correctly without false negatives or positives, and if they do, the command to print ip addresses can be assumed to work correctly. The third splitting function uses a regular expression, but in this case it's a trivial one without alternatives and optional atoms.

One important goal when writing robust and maintainable code is to keep functions cohesive and clear-cut without loopholes or irregularities. Matching with non-trivial regular expressions runs counter to this.

I certainly understand and actually applaud the wish to understand what went wrong, but the correct conclusion to draw from this is that regular expression matching *isn't a good method to use in this case*.

Comment: This does not answer the question - yes, it is BY FAR a better way to test an ip address, but it does nothing to answer "can anyone tell me how this happening"

Comment: _Rant mode on_ ... and another thing - one is not always lucky enough to have all necessary packages available or ability to add them everywhere one runs code (`can't find package ip`). We shouldn't say to never do something - there might be reasons... _Rant over_

Comment: @Captain: Tcllib_ip is a pure-Tcl module available by teacup or by normal download. You'd have to be extremely unlucky to be in a situation where you can't get it.Regarding answering the question: I usually attempt to do so and suggest better options as an aside. Helping people match ip addresses using regexps however is akin to giving them rope to hang themselves with.

Comment: I am looking for answer how this match happening, not different method.

Comment: @velpandian Although you didn't, you were told that there are better ways to do the same thing. Ultimately, it's up to you whether you want to use that or not, you are the one asking for help; people here are giving their time to help you free of charge. These same people could have spent that same time to do better things; things that could for example have brought them money. If you cannot even appreciate that, then it's just too bad.

Comment: Thanks all for your different approach and your comments. I am really sorry jerry and all, the way i asked is wrong. I know you all are giving very valuable idea to accomplish my task. I am new to TCL, when i try to write a pattern for matching ip by my own way, i found this problem. For making regexp concept clear i asked this question. That is the reason i asked how this happening.

Comment: @velpandian: while Jerry is right, all responses you get are of course provided freely with no strings attached. It's just the nature of this site that we often prefer to give the answer we believe the asker *needs* rather than the one s/he *wants*. In that way, answers become useful to more people, people that might not have your exact problem but are wondering about how to e.g. match ip addresses. One final un-asked-for advice: don't get yourself too bogged down in studying regular expressions. Their usefulness does not increase in proportion to expression complexity: simple is best.

Answer (score 0):

To answer "how this is happening" - ´.´ optional, it finds `1`, `0.`, `1`, `0.`

**And the answer to the unasked question**
The below expression will make the dot optional only if it is the end of the string (modified to ensure no trailing dot):

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.(?=[0-9])|$)){4}$
```

*Please remember* that the original question was asking "how is this happening" - i.e. understanding the regular expression behaviour... **NOTHING** about how to change the regex or how this should be done...

Comment: To whoever downvoted - could you please explain why this is not the answer to the question asked?

Comment: To nullify the downvoter +1 from me as this correctly answers the OP question. Also I suggest you to update your answer with the  correct version!

Comment: This allows trailing `.`

Comment: @nhahtdh - fixed the trailing . - even though this isn't really the answer to the question...

Comment: @Captain: Answering the question or not, as long as you post something, you need to make sure that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this regex:

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gW4fW6/2)

Comment: Although the question only asks why the match is happening, a nicer way to deal with the "optional" dot is `^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.|$)){4}$}` - i.e. "dot or the end"